# Serial Number and Version for Windows OS on KVM

Tags: windows, kvm, wmic

Does anyone know what will be output of : 
wmic get serialnumber, version

on windows guestOS running on KVM?

It would take too much time to install KVM just to get this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today is sunday and I don't have the access to my kvm hypervisor. But you can get it like the following :

```
SerialNumber                                         Version
9274-3370-7850-8629-2297-0860-94                     Kvm  - 0s
```

Have a look at this [link](https://blogs.technet.com/b/enterprise_admin/archive/2009/10/20/detecting-the-virtualization-layer-from-within-a-guest-child-instance.aspx) for detecting serialnumber or version in other hypervisors like esx, Hyper-V, xen .

Comment: Thanks, I just needed information where "Kvm" is located (in serial number or version) :)